# Execution error and ThreadPool use

Tags: .net, threadpool

I'd like to know, when adding a method for execution by using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, if there is a way to know when the job effectively starts and if the job ends without error (I want to raise HealthMonitoring event in case a problem happened) ?
Or are the error monitoring tasks must be done within the task itself ?

I'm currently using Framework 3.5 but we're heading toward the 4.5 in a few weeks (months). So if there's anything different in the latest version please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: QUWI is very low-level, you'd have to add all of your own plumbing to deal with exceptions.  Obvious ways to get ahead are BackgroundWorker (e.Error property for the RunWorkerCompleted event) and the Task class available in .NET 4

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll go check BackgroundWorker and Task